# deviceready event not consistently firing for non-index.html page

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm loading an external URL with PhoneGap 2.5, and trying to figure out why the deviceready event isn't consistently firing. There are a bunch of threads that all involved people not correctly adding the handlers, but I've done the following:

1. Put an `onload` handler on `body` where I do `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`
2. Used jQuery's document.ready function to set the event listener.
3. Called `setTimeout` in a loop waiting on navigator.splashscreen.

When does the `deviceready` event actually fire? Does loading a non-index.html page cause weird interactions? I see messages like `Resetting plugins due to page load.` and I'm wondering if that causes other problems.